# Ruby EventMachine, kill running processes?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

How can I kill running processes in EventMachine?
Below is an example, I'm starting 10 processes and then I'm trying to erase them all (but it doesn't work). My goal is to not have the "Finished" output.

```
require "rubygems"
require "eventmachine"

class Event
  def start
    sleep(5)
    puts Time.now.to_s + ": Finished!"
  end
end

EventMachine.run do
  events = []
  10.times {
    handle = Event.new
    events << handle

    EventMachine.defer(proc {
      handle.start
    })
  }

  # Terminate all events!
  events.each do |handle|
    handle = nil
    ObjectSpace.garbage_collect
  end
end
```

I'm aware that I could set a variable and check whether it's set when doing the output, but I feel like this isn't the "real" thing, or is this really the only solution there is?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`EventMachine.stop_event_loop`](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html#stop_event_loop-class_method), it will “cause all open connections and accepting servers to be run down and closed”.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but what if I only want to kill specific processes, not all?